# How to solve the error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"?

Tags: c, linked-list, warnings, dev-c++

Here is the piece of code: I wonder where my mistake is?
I have a structure named `country`, working with linked lists, and here is my function for searching:

```
country *search(char *v)
{
   country *c; c=head;
   while(c)
   {
           if(strcmp(c->name,v)==0)
           {return c;}
           c=c->next;
           if(c==head) break;}
           return (void *)-1;}
```

In `main` I have (`k` is a `int` variable):

```
printf("  \n\tEnter name of country for searching:   ");
                fflush(stdin); gets(v);
                k = search(v); // Function for searching
                if(k>=0)
                {puts("\n\t Info about Country: \n ");
```

When I compile this in Dev C++, I get:

```
[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of assigning the return value of `search` to a variable of type `int`, create a variable of type `country*` and assign the return value of `search` to that.

Comment: Please learn to use a more orthodox code layout; your code fragments are almost unreadable and very hard to comprehend because the layout is extraordinary — especially the first fragment.  Also, beware of [using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) and [why the `gets()` function cannot be used safely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: As @RSahu said, your function `search()` is declared to return a `country *`, so assigning its result to `k`, an `int`, is bound to give the error.  Return 0 or NULL for a missing value when the non-missing return type is a pointer.  Returning `(void *)-1` is aconventional (though not without standardized precedent).

Comment: What did you expect `k` to contain after running `k = search(v)`?

Comment: Doesn't the error messages together with the code line it issues says it all?

Comment: @immibis I expected an integer, I wondered it would be ok if k would contain the length of my string... or something like that

Comment: @alk the line of the code is: k = search(v);

Comment: @aB61 but how can it be an integer if `search` doesn't return an integer?

Comment: I know it is not possible... my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to fix:

1. The return value of `search` when you don't find what you are searching for:

   ```
   country *search(char *v)
   {
      country *c; c=head;
      while(c)
      {
         if(strcmp(c->name,v)==0)
         {
            return c;
         }
         c=c->next;
         if(c==head) break;
      }

      // Don't use -1 as an invalid search.
      // Use NULL instead.
      // return (void *)-1;
      return NULL;
   }
   ```
2. Use the right variable type to assign the return value of `search`.

   ```
   // Don't use k, which is of type int.
   // Use a variable of the right type.
   // k = search(v);
   country* cPtr = search(v);
   if( cPtr )
   {
      puts("\n\t Info about Country: \n ");
   }
   ```